# OpenTok framework in 64bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opentok, tokbox

Hi I am using OperTok SDK for video chating in my app. Everything works fine in my app. But when I try to run it in a 64 bit device/simulator - Build fails with below error report.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OTPublisher", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Instr_Video_call.o
  objc-class-ref in Student_Video_call.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OTSession", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Instr_Video_call.o
  objc-class-ref in Student_Video_call.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OTSubscriber", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Instr_Video_call.o
  objc-class-ref in Student_Video_call.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My Architecture set up is -

```
   ARCHITECTURES -  standard architectures armv7, armv7s, arm64
   VALID ARCHITECTURES -  armv7, armv7s, arm64
```

But when I chage these to only ARMV7 - it works (32bit devices/simulators)

What could be the issue, doesn't opentok support 64 bit devices ?
Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: You need get the 64 bit comparability OperTok SDK library

Comment: As far as I know, then last update to the OpenTok SDK was 2.3.0 which added support for armv7s. There hasn't been an update with arm64 support. So you'll have to remove arm64 support for your app (note: just remove arm64 from the architectures setting, not the valid architectures, that way your app will still run on 64-bit devices using 32-bit compiled code).

Comment: I have changed the Architectures to - armv7 only, but still the eroor comes ??

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the library contains 64bit code using lipo. The result shows it is a 32bit framework.

```
$ lipo -info OpenTok.framework/OpenTok 
Architectures in the fat file: OpenTok.framework/OpenTok are: armv7 armv7s i386
```

What you can do is to change `Build Active Architecture only` to `NO` in project settings and target settings, this way xcode will build all architecture included in the settings but lose some performance since arm64 is better option for 64bit iPhones.

Comment: arm64 support is coming to OpenTok, and until recently was blocked on Google updating the core webrtc libraries. no timeline at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

OpenTok 2.4.0 with 64 bit support has been released recently:
https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/ios/

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error due to enable bitcode.
Try to set enable bitcode "No"

Go to Targets - > Build Settings -> Search "Enable Bitcode" -> Set to "No"

That is solved my problem.

[image]